# CakePHP-2.0: How can i send email from a gmail account using CakEmail and SMTP setting?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send email from a gmail account using CakEmail and SMTP settings .

It would be nice if someone tell the process step by step what to do .

I have added the following in app/Config/email.php=>

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret'
    );
}
```

Now how can i send email to any email account from "my@gmail.com" ?

It's CakePHP-2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the docs:

You can configure SSL SMTP servers, like GMail. To do so, put the 'ssl://' at prefix in the host and configure the port value accordingly. Example:

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret'
    );
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html?highlight=cakeemail#CakeEmail

Answer (score 3):

The right configuration is:

```
public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

So, don't forget the **transport** element.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `from`:

```
<?php
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('my@gmail.com' => 'Your Name'));
$email->to('foo@stackoverflow.com');
$email->subject('Sent from Gmail');
$email->send('My message'); // or use a template etc
```

should do it.

You may want to set the `sender` as well; I'm not 100% but I imagine it will be useful when sending email "from" gmail via your own website; perhaps to stop the email being picked up as spam.

`$email->sender('noreply@mydomain.com', 'MyApp emailer');`

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a gmail account to send outbound mail.  I'm using templates and a reusable email setup function.  Here is a copy of my working code:

```
// app/controllers/users_controller.php
function sendemail($subject, $body, $to, $template) {
    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
        'port'=>'465',
        'timeout'=>'30',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'username@domain.com',
        'password'=>'secret',
    );
    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    //$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
    $this->Email->from    = 'Username <username@Domain.com>';
    $this->Email->to      = $to;
    $this->Email->subject = $subject;
    $this->set('body', $body);
    $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
    $this->Email->send($content, $template);
}

// app/controllers/users_controller.php 
// Excerpt from new user method in users controller:
function add() {
    // ...other stuff
    $body['user'] = $user['User']['username'];
    $this->sendemail('Domain.com New User Signup!', $body, 'destination@Domain.com', 'newuser');
    // ...other stuff
}

// app/views/elements/email/text/newuser.ctp
Everyone,
Another new user just signed up for Domain. Stats below:
User: <?php echo $body['user'] . "\r\r"; ?>
Just thought you'd like to know :)
-Janet
```

Comment: This is older email component.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Swiftmailer component; this is the easiest component to use.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mhuggins/2008/06/11/improved-swiftmailer-component

There are some changes that you need to do while using this with CakePHP 2.0 onwards.
CakePHP 2.0 provides an 'Emails' view directory, which is used to store all the email templates.

**Changes to the component:**

1. Change all `var` declarations to `public`
2. Change `public $layout = 'Emails';` to `public $viewPath = '/Emails';`
3. Change the render path in `_getBodyText`:

`$body = $this->controller->render($this->viewPath . DS . 'text' . DS . $view, $this->layout . DS . 'text'.DS.'default');`

4. Change the render path in `_getBodyHtml`:

`$body = $this->controller->render($this->viewPath . DS . 'html' . DS . $view, $this->layout . DS . 'html'.DS.'default');`

5. Comment out the lines:

`$bodyText = $this->_getBodyText($view);
$message->setBody($bodyText, "text/plain");`

The Swiftmailer component sends a blank email if you set both HTML & TEXT active. It reads from both the email views & adds the body for text. That's the reason to comment these two lines if you want to send html emails.

The second reason is if both are activated & you have content in both `email.html.ctp` & `email.text.ctp` files, it creates an header issue in that only the text format gets displayed in emails (in reality both the formats are present in header, but it suppresses the html part & shows the text part).