# Cakephp email functionality giving Unknown email configuration "gmail"

Tags: email, cakephp

I have written generating email functionality inside public function add().
My idea is to send my to the users who had registered.
my add functionality looks like this.
add functionality is working fine but mail generation giving error says Unknown email configuration "gmail". Any help please.
app/Controller/UsersController.php

```
 <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


    class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $this->User->create();
      if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

        $data[] =  $this->request->data;
        foreach($data as $row){
          $email_name = $row['User']['username'];
          $password = $row['User']['password'];
        }

        $data = array();
        $subject = "Visualization Tool Login credentials";
        // From
        $header="manasasirsi17@gmail.com";
        // Your message
        $message="welcome user\r\n";
        $message.="Thank You for Registering\r\n";
        $message.="your login details are as given below\r\n";
        $message.="username:$email_name\r\n";
        $message.="password:$password\r\n";

        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $smtp = new CakeEmail('smtp');
        $smtp->from(array($header => $header));
        $smtp->to($email_name);
        $smtp->subject($subject);

        $smtp->emailFormat('html');
        $Email->send($message);

       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login Details are sent to You via Email.'));
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
      return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'));
      } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

app/Config/email.php

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'manasasirsi17@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secure',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false

    );

    public $fast = array(
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        'sender' => null,
        'to' => null,
        'cc' => null,
        'bcc' => null,
        'replyTo' => null,
        'readReceipt' => null,
        'returnPath' => null,
        'messageId' => true,
        'subject' => null,
        'message' => null,
        'headers' => null,
        'viewRender' => null,
        'template' => false,
        'layout' => false,
        'viewVars' => null,
        'attachments' => null,
        'emailFormat' => null,
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've not defined a `gmail` email config in your `EmailConfig` class. This line:-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
```

should be from the looks of your code:-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
```

The parameter you pass to `CakeEmail` determines which of the defined configs in `EmailConfig` you want to use. If you had wanted to pass it `gmail` you would have needed to add a `$gmail` property to the `EmailConfig` class containing the configuration.

Comment: I edited my code as suggested as you.but it is giving error say stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:25 (Unknown error)

Comment: Because of that error i changed the port to 465 .Now the error says

Comment: @Manasa this appears to be a separate issue. By changing your code to use my answer CakePHP is now using the correct config, but it would seem your configuration is incorrect. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915318/cakephp-2-0-how-can-i-send-email-from-a-gmail-account-using-cakemail-and-smtp-s